# Why my implementation of Kuhn's algorithm doesn't work?

Tags: python, algorithm

I read about Kuhn's algorithm a few days ago and decided to implement it on Python. But this implementation doesn't pass some tests in online judge system. I've checked graph input and the main cycle, so I'm quite sure that parts of algorithm are correct. I assume this implementation fails to find an extension chain for matching, but I couldn't find a test for this case. Could you please help me to find the mistake? Here is the code:

```
def dfs(v) {
    if used[v]:
        return False
    used[v] = True
    for to in graph[v]:
        if match[to] == -1 or dfs(to):
            match[to] = v
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you please fix syntax error on line 1; provide a reproducible example with desired output and output from your program.

Comment: `match` seems to be poorly named -- it holds the DFS tree at the end of this code, not a matching.

Comment: Instead of `dfs(to)`, you need `dfs(match[to])`.  Also, of course, there's a lot of code left out, where errors may be hiding.